# make zsh tab complete after `alias vim="vim && clear"`?

Tags: bash, zsh, alias

I wanted to clear my terminal when exiting vim, because I kept switching through screen terminals and seeing old exited vim windows.

```
# .zshrc
alias vim="/usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0094/bin/vim && clear"
```

Tab completion (`$ vim ~/.vimr<TAB>`) did work when I had `alias vim=/bin/vim`, but with the `&& clear`, tab completion no longer works.

How can I continue to run `clear` after `vim` terminates and still have tab completion?

Comment: Seems that no arguments are passed at all, even if I type them out fully

Comment: Use a function instead: `function vim() { command vim "$@" && clear }`

Comment: Thanks @mpy, how do I invoke this new function from command line?

Comment: Exactly like you use an `alias`, so e.g. `vim test.txt` but also `vim` or `vim -n test.txt` is possible.